# How can I do assignment in a List Comprehension?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Generally, whenever I do a for loop in python, I try to convert it into a list comprehension.
Here, I have a for loop where a variable value is altered after each loop.

```
k=5
for x in range(1,6):
    k*=x
    print(k)
#output
5
10
30
120
600
```

I want to perform this operation in list comprehension. I tried doing but I was getting syntax error.
I tried this below:

```
[k*=x for x in range(1,6)]
```

Comment: You might need a reduce instead of a list. List comprehension is not a replacement of loops. List comprehension is a construction of a list. If you can use standard library `math`, `k = math.prod(range(1, 6), start=5)` will work. Or you can use `functools.reduce`. `functools.reduce(operator.mul, range(1, 6), 5)`

Comment: Don't use list comprehensions for side effects, that's not at all what they are meant for.

Comment: There is a walrus operator introduced in Python 3.8. Your solution would be `[k := k*x for x in range(1,6)]`. You can also update your `for` loop using it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use walrus operator (python 3.8+):

```py
k = 5
output = [k := k * x for x in range(1, 6)]

print(output) # [5, 10, 30, 120, 600]
```

But this pattern is not welcomed by some people.

Another option would be to use `itertools.accumulate`:

```py
from itertools import accumulate
from operator import mul

output = accumulate(range(1, 6), mul, initial=5)

print(*output) # 5 5 10 30 120 600
```

In this case the initial value `5` is attached at the beginning.

Comment: a little modification to your first option: [print(k := k * x) for x in range(1, 6)]

Comment: @Ze'evBen-Tsvi No, I don't want to do that. I don't use a list comprehension for such side effects.