# Find fibonacci series upto N terms using list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, fibonacci, python-assignment-expression

Need to find the Fibonacci series up to N terms.

```
n=int(input("Enter the n terms: "))
f_val=0
fib_list=[f_val:=f_val + i for i in range(n)]
print(fib_list)
```

While executing the above program, I got the result:

```
Enter the n terms:  5
[0, 1, 3, 6, 10]
```

My doubt is: what is the purpose of `f_val := f_val + i`? I really don't know the purpose of `:=` in Python. Can anyone help me to find the solution?

Comment: `:=` is called walrus operator

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Walrus Operator(Python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74106306/walrus-operatorpython)

Comment: You aren't getting the Fibonacci numbers; you're getting the triangular numbers.

Answer (score -2):

```py
n = int(input("Enter the number of terms: "))

f_val = 0
fib_list = [f_val := f_val + (fib_list[i-1] if i > 0 else 1) for i in range(n)]

print(fib_list)
```

Correct the code
and solution of your doubt is:
`f_val` is the variable that stores the current value of the Fibonacci-like series.
`f_val + i` calculates the next term by adding the current value of `f_val` with the loop variable `i`.
`f_val := f_val + i` assigns the new calculated value to `f_val` for the next iteration.

Comment: Did you run your code?

Comment: `fib_list` isn't defined yet while the list comprehension is executing. Only after the right-hand side is fully evaluated is the result assigned to the name `fib_list`.